# What is the term for multiple-long phrases in a single sentence?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs, modifiers

> The bark of the tree had progressively gained pallor and, **like some
>   town under siege**, **thanks to the repeated assaults of snowstorms
>   and subzero temperatures**, it was hard to imagine how this tree would
>   survive.

1. What is the purpose of the bold phrases in the above sentence?
2. What are the bold phrases called in English grammar (in relation to my question)?
3. What is the standard English grammar rule when it comes to a series of phrases like those?

Comment: It's called multi-clausal sentences, as they contain more than 1 clause.

Answer (score 1):

The first bolded construction is a [*simile*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simile), a figure of speech where two usually unlike things are compared using *like* or *as*, in this case a tree with sickly bark and a town under siege. This comparison is extended by the use of the word *assaults* to describe harsh winter weather. The simile and its extension in a subordinate clause, however, serve a larger rhetorical goal.

A [*periodic sentence*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_sentence) is one which is not grammatically or semantically complete until the end:

> Like the waters of the river, like the motorists on the highway, and like the yellow trains streaking down the Santa Fe tracks, drama, in the shape of exceptional happenings, had never stopped there. — Truman Capote, *[In Cold Blood](https://www.thoughtco.com/periodic-sentence-grammar-and-prose-style-1691607)*, 1966.

The subject *drama* does not make an entrance until after three similes, the first two with the same rhythm, but then is separated from the predicate by yet another nested prepositional construction: *in the shape of exceptional happenings*. This technique has often been described as [*suspended syntax*](https://www.thoughtco.com/periodic-sentence-grammar-and-prose-style-1691607), since readers are required to keep the three similes in suspension until they know what is being compared, *drama*, then must wait yet again for the verb. Drama and suspense, of course is what this technique is all about.

While Capote’s sentence is not *grammatically* complete until the end, your example is not *semantically* complete until the actual topic of the sentence — that the tree is all but dying — is revealed at the end. The independent clause at the beginning merely establishes the color of the bark.

There are no grammar rules per se governing this type of style, only stylistic guidelines, the first of which must be never attempt more than two subordinating elements until you have mastered the technique. Long periodic sentences are not merely a feature of high oratory, but good storytelling as well. In the hands of less gifted writers, however, the style can seem tiresome, affected, or antiquated.

Answer (score 0):

"Like some town under siege" is  a simile, "a figure of speech comparing two unlike things that is frequently introduced using like or as," MW. The simile in this case compares the tree to a town under siege. The phrase "thanks to the repeated assaults of snowstorms and subzero temperatures," explains why the simile is accurate. The point of this simile is to make the condition of the tree more vivid to the reader. "Thanks to" works like the preposition "because of." I think the simile works well, and the sentence is probably from a 19th Century Russian or English novel.

Comment: Question is corrected, one comma is added just after first "and", please respond.

Comment: Link from where is the text is copied:http://www.thehindu.com/todays-paper/tp-opinion/the-sound-of-silence-in-a-bustling-metropolis/article23469540.ece